# Alternatives to Entity Framework Power Tools with Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am a recreational/novice coder and I'm trying to work through some MVC 4 / Entity Framework tutorials on the MSDN website to learn a new framework.

The [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620) makes reference to EF Power Tools Beta 3 but I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web and it doesn't look like I can install those tools against it. As I recreational coder, I can't really justify paying $499 for the full version of Visual Studio.

Does anyone know of an alternative for generating the code to map to the database or do I have to type it by hand (don't know it yet!)?

Many Thanks

Comment: you dont need the powertools to use EF they are for some pretty specific extras :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can always use the designer that reverse engineer the database and create code for you. As far as I remember it is supported on express SKUs. Create a project, Add New Item, select ADO .NET Entity Framework Model (or something along these lines), in the wizard select Model from the database and you should have code and the model in form of EDMX file. AFAIR Power Tools add on creates a CodeFirst model - so you don't have the edmx file. This is preferred but to get started and experiment the Designer should be sufficient.